# Using DateTimeFormatter on january first cause an invalid year value

Tags: java

When i'm using a DateTimeFormatter (code bellow) on a LocalDate set to January 1st 2017 i am ending with a wrong year value.

```
LocalDate.of(2017,1,1).toString
```

This will properly display 2017-01-01 while

```
LocalDate.of(2017,1,1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM YYYY"))
```

Is giving me: 
01 janv. 2016. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Use `y` instead of `Y`. This is the week-based year. See [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). I guess @Robby use a different Local where (Sunday is the first day of the week)

Comment: Thank you @AxelH, that was it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your are using the "wrong" year.

```
 Symbol  Meaning            Presentation    Examples  
 ------  -------            ------------    -------  
 y       year-of-era        year            2004; 04  
 Y       week-based-year    year            1996; 96
```

Source : [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

This is basically using the first day of the current week to see in what year it was instead of the actual day.

One of the issues is that this is Local dependent...

You should have used `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy")`.